# Codeigniter Form field with dynamic id validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can i validate fields with names like this

```
<select name="mechanic_134" id="mechanic-134" class="form-control selectpicker">
```

mechanic_ is the general field name &  134 is a id i am getting from database. there are more fields to come like mechanic_135........mechanic_150.

i want to know how can i validate this field with dynamic id. please show it in code level. how it is done in controller & how the error output in view

Have a look (view)

http://www.screencast.com/t/jhXvVBUH

i have tried this in my controller but i don't know how to show this in view (the error message)

```
foreach ($this->input->post() as $key=>$value) {
  if (! strpos('mechanic_',$key) === FALSE ) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($key, 'Mechanic', 'trim|required');
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear, be more specific and show your view and controller.

Comment: How you are passing the data to the controller?

Comment: @parth all i need is a validation rule to validate these select fields (select fields cannot be empty).  i do have a controller & on it at the moment i have the database part. just need the validation part to complete

Comment: You have to pass id from the hidden field, you can't pass id like this.

Comment: How you are passing the data to the controller? are you using jquery ajax post method ? if so .. then i have suggestion for you. . if you just get all the select box **names,ids**  using **jquery's find method based on dom** at submit and pass it to it while you do ajax post and in your controller , just forloop it with the name you get for validation .. what are your thoughts for the same ?